Typographically correct spacing between letter pairs in math mode
Sometimes some letter combinations in math mode have to much space between them. For example, when applying an operator V to a function f inserting a negative thinmuskip between V and f looks better to me. In case of T and f, a negative thinmuskip seems a little bit too close and I would use more space. \mathit has to little space and introduces a space before the first letter. Is there a way to automatically insert kerning between certain letter pairs in math mode? Or is the regular spacing actually correct?

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
$\begin{array}{lllll}
    (Vf)(x) & Vx & (Tf)(x) & Tx & \\
    (V\!f)(x) & V\!x & (T\!f)(x) & T\!x & \verb+-\thinmuskip+ \\
    (\mathit{Vf})(x) & \mathit{Vx} & (\mathit{Tf})(x) & \mathit{Tx} & \verb+\mathit+
\end{array}$
\end{document}


Can you specify: Who decides what is correct?

@mickep I mean by the typography conventions in mathematics.

the mathitalic font has wide sidebearings and is designed so that adjacent letters look like a product of single letter variables, so if you are not encoding such a product then extra markup is expected, either spacing or commonly using a different font for functions. In your examples  T!f looks way too close, but also you should use the same x or f everywhere so if using mathit then \mathit{V}x  not \mathit{Vx} 

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your response. I actually meant that the spacing in T!f is too tight and I would use more space. I have tried \mathit{V}x but then the spacing between V and x seems to be the same as in Vx.

\! is usually -3mu so you could try \mskip-1mu or whatever

@DavidCarlisle Thank you. Is there an automatic way? I mean, is it possible to specify the spacing once for certain letter pairs?
